# Copy and Paste Dynamic Range from One Worksheet to Another

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I am attempting to copy column A starting in row 2 on "Sheet1" and paste it in Column C on sheet "ABC" starting at row 5.  The number of rows in Column A is variable so I cannot use a fixed range.

The code below does what I need, but I am trying to avoid using .Select and .Activate

```
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets("ABC").Activate
Sheets("ABC").Range("C5:C" & LastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I tried setting the columns equal to one another using this code:

```
  Sheets("ABC").Range("C5").End(xlDown).Value=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
```

This runs without error but it "does nothing" -- No data appears on worksheet "ABC"

I also tried to following:

```
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim wsABC As worksheet


    Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsABC = Sheets("ABC")
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    WS.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy
    wsABC.Range("C5").End(xlDown).Paste
```

This produces a "Run-time error #438 Object doesn't support this property or method" Error on this line:

```
 wsABC.Range("C5").End(xlDown).Paste
```

Another method I tried was as follows:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsABC = Sheets("ABC")


  With WS
  LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  WS.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).value = wsABC.Range("C5:C & LastRow").Value

End With
```

This produces a "Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error.

I am open to corrections / comments on any of my attempts, I just want to avoid using .Select and .Activate.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coding styles can vary greatly.  Here's one way to do what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("ABC")

    With wsData.Range("A2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        wsDest.Range("C5").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Worksheets("ABC").Range("C5").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```